# VSO Release — RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: azure-pipelines

***Error Info:***

```
 18:05:28 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
 18:05:28     at RegExp.exec (native) 
 18:05:28     at win32SplitPath (path.js:95:29) 
 18:05:28     at Object.win32.dirname (path.js:331:16) 
 18:05:28     at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\Agent\modules\vso-task-lib\0.4.5\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:7:22) 
 18:05:28     at mkdirSyncRecursive (D:\Agent\modules\vso-task-lib\0.4.5\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
```

***Release Definition:***

- Only one task: Windows Machine File Copy: Source, Machine, Admin Login: all good.

I also tried Utility-Copy-File Task, same error.

Kindly please help.

Comment: Worked around by using Publish Task, initially cannot pass, later changed solution mode from debug to release, checked in, also changed VSO Build from debug to release as well, then passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a straight answer, rather just Worked around by using Publish Task, initially cannot pass, later changed solution mode from debug to release, checked in, also changed VSO Build from debug to release as well, then passed.

Answer (score 1):

I found this error:

```
shell.js: internal error 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
   at String.charCodeAt (native)
   at Object.dirname (path.js:706:21)
   at mkdirSyncRecursive
```

The error for TFS Release (on premise) was that a long time ago, (about network password change period), the build agents were set up under a specific user (not a service account). That user got prompted to change his password, so he/she did. The windows service on the build agent, couldn't presumably "log in" to get access to a network share. Switched to a service account without an expiring password (like you're supposed to), and fixed!

Comment: this reminded me I had not setup the UNC share or folder permissions yet and doing so resolved my problem.